# How can I get the HTML of a hidden element in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I have a hidden div on a page I'd like to get a reference to in Cypress so I can get its text and assert on it. As far as I can tell from the API docs I don't see any way to do this. You can use the `{ force : true }` option to force Cypress to click on something it doesn't think it can, but there's no option for that to force Cypress to look for elements that are not visible to the user, but are in the dom.

The element is hidden on the dom by a `display: none` style. This is just one of the many reasons Cypress will consider an element "hidden" and not find it. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/interacting-with-elements.html#Visibility

I have read through the API docs and mostly tried cypress.get()

Comment: Please provide more info, including what you have tried and why the div is hidden (another element covers, display none, width & height 0).

Comment: as per the documentation "In all versions of Cypress, you can interact with elements that have opacity: 0 style."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created a hidden `div` in my html, the below test run successfully in Cypress. The display property for that div in `css` `#hiddenDiv1{
display:none;
}`

```
describe('Hidden text', function() {
  it.only('Test for the hidden text', function() {
   cy.visit('url goes here')
   cy.get('#hiddenDiv1').invoke('text')
      .then((text)=>{
        const divTxt = text;
        expect(divTxt).to.contain('Life is Beautiful!');
      })

  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

When I am searching for something that is hidden, I always just add `.should('not.be.visible')` to the search, and it picks it up.

Not sure if that's right for you, but hope that helps.

Comment: I used to do this in version 4 and 5
but it will not work if you upgrade to version 6

Comment: For version 6, you may need: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/migration-guide.html#Non-existent-element-assertions

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution to your problem.

```
cy.get('div[class="class name"]').contains('text').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you for example try to find a `button` by for example a `span` or other element containing a hidden text to be able click on it you can do like this:

```
// get the hidden element then get the first parent that is supposed to be a button
cy.get('[data-cy="container"]').contains('hidden text').should('not.be.visible')
                               .parent('button').click();
```

Beware that according to [the docs about the `parent` command here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/parent) it only:

> travels a single level up the DOM tree

So if it is not a direct sibling of the button, but deeper nested, you should use the `parents` command instead:

```
// get the hidden element then get the first parent that is a button
cy.get('[data-cy="container"]').contains('hidden text').should('not.be.visible')
                               .parents('button').first().click();
```

Note that using `first()` is probably never needed (since buttons will most likely not be nested inside other buttons).